# Evading router website filtering

Tags: router, internet

I'm helping a relative out at his office, he's got website filtering enabled on his router (a D-Link DIR-600) to block Youtube and Facebook, yet somehow his employees are able to access these sites anyways. Each of them has a company-supplied laptop that they use to access the network wirelessly. They have full control over the laptops and can install and access practically any portion of it (this is another issue, but I'll address that later).

I've checked settings on the browsers they use (Firefox and Chrome), and they don't appear to have changed anything, and clearing out browser history/cookies doesn't seem to work either, so I'm guessing the problem must be further in.

EDIT: I brought a laptop from home and connected to their network to see what was up. I tried entering the url straight into my browser and was promptly blocked, but the Facebook page that I already had open and logged into my personal account would refresh just fine and I could even visit friends pages.

Any ideas on where I could look next?

Comment: Did you check their DNS settings? Make sure they're using the router and not Google's or your ISP's.

Comment: He will have to reolve the fact these employees have full control over the hardware.  It sounds like he needs more agressive filtering solutions then the router solution.

Comment: Yes, quick Ipconfig tells me that both default gateway and DNS servers are the office router.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the site he is blocking is explicit to the page.

EG, www.facebook.com is blocked, but www.facebook.com/thisPage is accessable.

Ensure he is blocking by domain name or by IP. Also consider sub domains.

Answer (score 0):

If your allowed to install softwares install the `Tor` Bundle. This will help you connect via a anonymous network. Also another utility which we used was `Ultrasurf` to access blocked sites.

Many times just making a explicit`https://www.facebook.com` would pass a simple filter instead of `**http**://www.facebook.com` .